# Правильное склонение слова "Саргассы"

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, будьте добры, по ту сторону Саргасс или по ту сторону Саргассов?

Answer (score 1):

Саргассами назван гидроним, Саргассово море?

Тогда - по ту сторону Саргасс.

ИМХО.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще такие вещи надо проверять по словарям имен собственных. 
Но в нашем случае название это разговорное, четкой фиксации может и не быть. Отсюда и колебания.

Тем не менее. Есть простая и очевидная логика. Саргасс - водоросль, мужского рода. К исключениям типа "партизан", "солдат", "туркмен", "татар" отношения явно не имеет - там все сплошь о людях. Да и море само ***Саргассово***. Не "*Саргассное*".

Так почему не "Саргассов"-то?! Видимо, какая-то ошибочная аналогия возникла у приверженцев формы "Саргасс" (р.п. мн.).

Answer (score 0):

1. В толковом словаре Кузнецова указаны две формы:
   [сарга́ссы](https://gufo.me/amp/dict/kuznetsov/%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B), **-а́сс** и **-ов**; *мн.* Морские бурые водоросли, наиболее распространённые в центральной части Атлантического океана. *Кусты саргассов.*

Вариативность склонения наблюдается, например, у Александра Беляева ("Остров погибших кораблей"):
*Еще с вечера «Вызывающий» вступил в полосу, свободную от саргасс.

Завтра мы повернем на север, в самую гущу саргасс.

Наконец седьмого августа появились сплошные луга саргассов.*

2. Полная акцентуированная парадигма по А. А. Зализняку: [сарга́ссов](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-96627.htm) (то есть только одна возможная форма).
   Если бы мне пришлось выбирать, я бы ее и предпочла: по ту сторону саргассов.

*Пятна пожелтелых на солнце саргассов...* (Э. Хемингуэй); *Веточки саргассов, усыпанные «виноградинами», изящно покачивались...* (И. Туманова); книга [*Чудовища Саргассов*](https://knigism.online/view/263590) (Карл-Йеско фон Путткамер).

Comment: Здесь Саргассы - гидроним (Саргассово море), то есть с заглавной. Но а остальном согласен.

Comment: Странно, что другие участники не согласны. Мне кажется, что при склонении разницы нет (саргассы или Саргассы) — происхождение-то слова одинаковое (от водорослей). Плыли через саргассы (через водоросли) или плыли через Саргассы (через море, наполненное водорослями); по ту сторону саргассов или по ту сторону Саргассов.

Comment: *Странно, что другие участники не согласны* - В принципе-то у них есть некоторые основания. Имена собственные могут иметь отличия в склонениях.  Иногда системные, нормированные (любовь - Любовь), иногда ничем кроме лингвистического казуса не объяснимые (г. Пески,  из Песок). Но это все общие разговоры, применительно к нашему случаю подобного не наблюдается.